# O(n log(n)) algorithm that checks if sum of 2 numbers in a int[] = given number

Tags: java, big-o, binary-search

I am supposed to create a `O(n log(n))` algorithm that checks if sum of 2 numbers in a int[] == given number.

eg. Given [1,4,7,2,3,4] there will be a sum 8 (1+7) but not 20

The given answer suggested Binary Sort or Merge Sort, but they just gave the merge sort algorithm without the logic processing this particular requirement. Then another answer was:

> Suppose x is the sum we want to check, z is the set of elements in
>   this array: The following algorithm solves the problem:
>
> 1. Sort the elements in S.
> 2. Form the set S’ = {z : z = x − y for some y ∈ S}.
> 3. Sort the elements in S'.
> 4. If any value in S appears more than once, remove all but one instance. Do the same for S’.
> 5. Merge the two sorted sets S and S’.
> 6. There exist two elements in S whose sum is exactly x if and only if the same value appears in consecutive positions in the merged output.
>
> To justify the claim in step 4, first observe that if any value
>   appears twice in the merged output, it must appear in consecutive
>   positions. Thus, we can restate the condition in step 5 as there exist
>   two elements in S whose sum is exactly x if and only if the same value
>   appears twice in the merged output. Suppose that some value w appears
>   twice. Then w appeared once in S and once in S’. Because w appeared in
>   S’, there exists some y ∈ S such that w = x − y, or x = w + y. Since w
>   ∈ S, the elements w and y are in S and sum to x.
>
> Conversely, suppose that there are values w, y ∈ S such that w + y =
>   x. Then, since x − y = w, the value w appears in S’. Thus, w is in
>   both S and S’, and so it will appear twice in the merged output.
>
> Steps 1 and 3 require O(n log n) steps. Steps 2, 4, 5, and 6 require
>   O(n) steps. Thus the overall running time is O(n log n).

But I don't really what they meant. In step 2, what are x and y?

But I created by own below, I wonder if its `O(n log(n))`?

```
class FindSum {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {6,1,2,3,7,12,10,10};
    int targetSum = 20;

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    int end = arr.length - 1;
    if (FindSum.binarySearchSum(arr, targetSum, 0, end, 0, end)) {
      System.out.println("Found!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not Found :(");
    }
  } 

  public static boolean binarySearchSum(int[] arr, int targetSum,
                                        int from1, int end1,
                                        int from2, int end2) {
    // idea is to use 2 "pointers" (simulating 2 arrays) to (binary) search 
    // for target sum
    int curr1 = from1 + (end1-from1)/2;
    int curr2 = from2 + (end2-from2)/2;
    System.out.print(String.format("Looking between %d to %d, %d to %d: %d, %d", from1, end1, from2, end2, curr1, curr2));
    int currSum = arr[curr1] + arr[curr2];
    System.out.println(". Sum = " + currSum);

    if (currSum == targetSum) { 
      // base case
      return true;
    } else if (currSum > targetSum) { 
      // currSum more than targetSum
      if (from2 != end2) { 
        // search in lower half of 2nd "array"
        return FindSum.binarySearchSum(arr, targetSum, from1, end1, from2, curr2 - 1);
      } else if (from1 != end2) { 
        // search in lower half of 1st "array" (resetting the start2, end2 args)
        return FindSum.binarySearchSum(arr, targetSum, from1, curr1 - 1, 0, arr.length - 1);
      } else {
        // can't find
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // currSum < targetSum
      if (from2 != end2) { 
        // search in upper half of 2nd "array"
        return FindSum.binarySearchSum(arr, targetSum, from1, end1, curr2 + 1, end2);
      } else if (from1 != end2) { 
        // search in upper half of 1st "array" (resetting the start2, end2 args)
        return FindSum.binarySearchSum(arr, targetSum, curr1 + 1, end1, 0, arr.length - 1);
      } else {
        // can't find
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what a convoluted way to solve an easy task. The one from algorithm description that is.

Comment: 3. Sort the elements in [the set] S'. Ugh. Can't sort sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to @user384706, however you can do this with in `O(n)`.

What they say is the following:
S=[1,4,7,2,3,4]

Add these to a HashSet, ideally TIntHashSet (but the time complexity is the same)

```
int total = 9;
Integer[] S = {1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(S));
for (int i : set)
    if (set.contains(total - i))
        System.out.println(i + " + " + (total - i) + " = " + total);
```

prints

```
2 + 7 = 9
3 + 6 = 9
6 + 3 = 9
7 + 2 = 9
```

Comment: How do you know this is O(n)?  If this was implemented in HW, you'd have to assume that the worst case for the Hash access is O(n) because all the hash entries could collide, i.e. be in the same location.  Does SW get a free pass to assume that hash access is always O(1)?

Comment: @JamesTesta in this case every element get a different bucket.  You can assume O(1) lookups or close to it in reasonable usage patterns.  Where this assumption breaks down is in denial of service attacks, but normally this is not an issue.

Answer (score 6):

What they say is the following:
`S=[1,4,7,2,3,4]`

Sort S using mergesort you get `Ss=[1,2,3,4,7]`. Cost is `O(nlogn)` - just check wiki for this.

Then you have `x=8`
So you form `S'=[7,6,5,4,1]` by subtracting `x` with the elements in `S`.
Sort `S'` using mergesort in `O(nlogn)`
Remove duplicates requires `O(n)`.

Then you merge the `Ss` and `S'`.
You check for duplicates in consecutive positions in `O(n)`.
Total is:
`O(nlogn)+O(nlogn)+O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(nlogn)`

Comment: @soulcheck:I am just explaining what he was given as a template.I don't think the OP even knows what merge-sort is.

Answer (score 3):

What about an *O(n)* solution?

It's not clear from your question if you're supposed to use what you described as "another answer" [sic] or if you can come up with your own solution.

The first thing you should ask is "what are the requirements?"  Because there are limitations.  What's the maximum number of integers you'll receive?  Two millions?  Ten millions?   What's the range of these integers?  In your question they always seem greater than zero.  What's the maximum value these integers can have?  How much memory can you use?

Because there are *always* tradeoffs.

For example here's a non-optimized (see below) *O(n)* solution to your problem (I added an '8' to your input):

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    final int max = 10000000;
    final int[] S = new int[max+1];
    final int[] in = { 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8 };
    for ( final int i : in ) {
        S[i]++;
    }
    assertFalse( containsSum(S, 1) );
    assertFalse( containsSum(S, 2) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 3) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 4) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 5) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 6) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 7) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 8) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 9) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 10) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 11) );
    assertFalse( containsSum(S, 13) );
    assertFalse( containsSum(S, 14) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 12) );
    assertTrue( containsSum(S, 15) );
    assertFalse( containsSum(S, 16) );
}

private static boolean containsSum( final int[] ar, final int sum ) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < sum && !found; i++) {
            final int b = sum - i;
            found = i == b ? ar[i] > 1 : ar[i] > 0 && ar[b] > 0;
    }
    return found;
}
```

It's non optimized in that it's easy to write an *O(n)* working for integers from 0 to 2**31 using "only" 1 GB of memory (where you'd represent your S and your S' using bits instead of ints like I did here).

Sure, one may think *"but 1GB is a lot of memory"*: but it all depends on the requirements.  My solution above (or an optimized version of it) is *O(n)* and can solve an input made of, say, 100 millions integers in no time, where any other solution would fail (because you'd have *OutOfMemory* errors due to the overhead of Java objects).

The first thing to ask is *"What are the requirements?"*.  You need more information about the input because it's always a tradeoff.

Comment: if there are no assumptions mentioned then it should be treated as 'without any extra assumptions on the input data'.

Comment: Hard to believe someone did downvote this...  *"Without any extra assumptions on the input data"* doesn't mean anything: we're tied to the limit of our computational devices.  Are we supposed to use *BigInteger* because integers can be *really* big?  But then how many integers can we have?  It's really weird to downvote this when using this method can solve the problem where any other solution not using *BigInteger* would fail...

Comment: yeah, it was my (I admit, too quick) downvote and i can't cancel it unless you edit your answer, so just do a noop edit and i'll take it back.

Comment: besides you can do this test in-place once the input array is already in memory, so where's the OutOfMemory error you mentioned then?

Comment: another thing that needs comment: you HAVE to pack it into bit array, not because of memory requirements, but because arrays in java are int indexed, so if you are unfortunate enough to work with input data that contains Integer.MAX_VALUE you'll get NegativeArraySizeException.

Comment: @soulcheck: I may not have been clear enough: my point is that if you use any collection backed by objects (like, say, a HashSet) you'd be losing memory due to the huge overhead of every single object compared to a single *int*.  Putting 100 million *int* in an int[] "only" require allocating a 400 MB array but this is very doable: try putting these same 100 million integers in a HashSet and you'll have quite some surprises.  I should edit my answer and add example comparing a default *HashSet*, Trove's TIntHashSet and a bit-packed array.

Comment: @soulcheck: regarding *Integer.MAX_VALUE*: that is kinda precisely my point: how convenient is it that in a problem where the requirements are badly lacking the max value of the "integer" would happen to be *Integer.MAX_VALUE*? That is totally arbitrary. Which is why I'm putting the emphasis on the fact that the problem, as is, is very, very, badly underspec'ed. It's all about tradeoffs, nearly all the time: give me hundreds of millions of integers in the [1..10000000] range and my O(n) solution is the best. Give me only a few thousand integer in the [1..2**63-1] range and you need BigInteger.

Comment: @soulcheck: I agree that creating an *int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]* (does that even work on 64-bit VMs? ; )  ain't a smart idea.  But if the range is precisely [1...Integer.MAX_VALUE] and if we could allocate such a gigantic array, then one could simply make the array simply starting from 0, instead of 1 [0 being unused in my example].  But anyway it wasn't my point: I was just showing why problems like this are typically badly lacking in requirements and why requirements are important : )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4983/discussion-between-soulcheck-and-user988052)

Comment: this algorithm opened by eyes to a different way of thinking about problems, thanks so much and upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(n log n). Each time you either divide 1st array size by two or do a binary search on the second one. This is O((log n) ^2)  worst case (ie. S = {1,2...,n} and x = 0) and hence it's absorbed by sorting.

Anyway you can do it a bit easier in O(n log n) by:

1. sorting the array (O(n log n))
2. iterating it's elements (O(n)) while in each iteration  binary searching (O(log n)) for X-complement of the current element.

edit:
In response to your first question. x is the sum you're looking for and y are the elements of the input set. So if S= {y_1, y_2, y_3,..., y_n} then S' = {x - y_1, x - y_2, x - y_3, ...x - y_n}

Comment: why downvotes? both worst case analysis and the algorithm are ok!

Answer (score 0):

It works as following :

1. Sort the Input array
2. create two variables front=0 [start point] rear=length of array [end point].
3. It starts from both end of array calculate sum of it if it zero increment both front and rear
4. if not increment the side which contains greater element.[since Array is sorted there is not chance to find element such that their sum is 0]
5. stop when front >=rear.

---

```
public class TwoSumFaster {

private static int countTwoSum(int[] numbers) {
    int count = 0;
    int front = 0, rear = numbers.length - 1;

    while (front < rear) {
        if (numbers[front] + numbers[rear] == 0) {
            front++;
            rear--;
            count++;
        } else {
            if (Math.abs(numbers[front]) > Math.abs(numbers[rear])) {
                front++;
            } else {
                rear--;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 16, 19, 15, 11, 8, -1, -3, -7, -8, -11, -17, -15 };
    Arrays.sort(numbers); 
    System.out.println(countTwoSum(numbers));
}
```

}