# Java: How to implement 3 sum?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, list

I'm studying the 3 Sum to implement it on my own, and came across the following implementation with the rules:

> Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.
>
> Note: Elements in a triplet (a,b,c) must be in non-descending order. (ie, a ≤ b ≤ c)
> The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

```
For example, given array S = {-1 0 1 2 -1 -4},

A solution set is:
(-1, 0, 1)
(-1, -1, 2)
```

And implementation (sorts the array, iterates through the list, and uses another two pointers to approach the target):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ThreeSum {
    List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] num) {
        Arrays.sort(num);
        List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>(); 
        
        for (int i=0; i<num.length-2; i++) {
            if (i==0 || (i>0 && num[i] != num[i-1])) { //HERE
                int lo = i+1;
                int hi = num.length-1;
                int sum = 0 - num[i];
                
                while (lo < hi) {
                    if (num[lo] + num[hi] == sum) {
                        res.add(Arrays.asList(num[i], num[lo], num[hi]));
                        while (lo < hi && num[lo] == num[lo+1]) lo++; //HERE
                        while (lo < hi && num[hi] == num[hi-1]) hi--; //HERE
                        lo++; hi--;
                        
                    } else if (num[lo] + num[hi] < sum) lo++;
                    else hi--; 
               }
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
    
    //Driver
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreeSum ts = new ThreeSum();
        int[] sum = {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
        
        System.out.println(ts.threeSum(sum));
    }
}
```

And my question is (located where commented: //HERE), what's the reason for checking `num[i] != num[i-1]`, `num[lo] == num[lo+1]`, and `num[hi] == num[hi-1]`? Supposedly they are supposed to skip the same result, but what does that mean? Examples would really help.

Thank you in advance and will accept answer/up vote.

Comment: That' s always the same logic, if there are two identical values, you would end with same triplet result, so you skip it. This could be done by simply removing duplicate in the list I guess.

Comment: @AxelH No, one cannot remove duplicates - triplet with duplicate {-1-1,2} is valid

Comment: @MBo How, indeed ! DIdn't think about that

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have `{-1,-1,0,1,2,4}` and considering triplet num[0], num[2], num[3] (-1,0,1).

`lo=0` here. To exclude triplet num[1], num[2], num[3] with the same values, we should increment `lo` and pass over duplicate

Comment: by duplicates, does it mean there is no need to calculate the same triplet sum twice (such as (-1, 0, 1) and calculate (-1, 0, 1) again since there are two -1), or the triplet sum cannot have duplicates even though they ==0, such as (-1, -1, 2)?

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent the list to have duplicate triplet.

For example, with you test :

```
int[] sum = {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
```

will be sorted like :

```
sum = {-4, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2};
```

You see that you have `-1` twice. Without these test, you would test twice if `-1 = 0 + 1`. This is not usefull so the algo simply search the next different value.

<s>You could remove duplicate in the sorted List to prevent these test.</s>

Thanks to MBo, we can't remove duplicate since we can have triplet with same value (but with different index)

Answer (score 1):

**All the three sentences is used to avoid the duplicate output.**
Consider a sorted list
 `{-2, -2 , 1, 1}`
If there is no checking for `num[i] != num[i-1]`, the output of the program would be
`(-2, 1, 1)`and`(-2, 1, 1)`, 
which are two duplicate triplets.
The checking for `num[lo] != num[lo + 1]`and `num[hi] != num[hi - 1]` are for the same reason.
Consider a sorted list

```
{-2,-1,-1,0,3}
```

If there is no checking for num[lo], you will get `(-2,-1,3)` and `(-2,-1,3)` as the output.


Still, I want to recommend a better solution for this problem. You can numerate the sum of two numbers in the list and find the 3rd number by hash or binary search. It will helps you to gain a O(n^2logn) time complexity rather than O(n^3). (I was wrong, the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2), sorry for that.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Before I answer the question,how did you calculate the time complexity to be O(n^3)? What would be a good quick way to see an implementation and tell the time complexity right away?

Comment: @JoKo I was  with that, your algorithm seems to be O(n^2). It's the best solution for three sum. Sorry for my careless.

Comment: No worries but how is it O(n^2)? What tipped it off?

Comment: Forget the code. Let's just pay attention to the algorithm itself.

Comment: The first step sort will cost at least O(nlogn). The second step to find triplets in a sorted list can be viewed as  O(n) execution of finding doublets whose sum is  a certain value in a sorted list. And it is apparently that find those doublets in a sorted list is O(n). So the complexity of the second step is O(n*n) . O(n^2) + O(nlogn) is still O(n^2).

Comment: @YuGu Sorry but which part is finding the doublets that represents O(n)? I get since it is a for loop, it is O(n), but don't get inner O(n) part.

Comment: @Ly Maneug The loop of while(lo<hi) is inner O(n) to find the doublets.

Answer (score 1):

Following program finds pairs of three integer with O(N*2)

1. Sort the input Array
2. and iterate each element in for loop and check for sum in program which is developed for Two sum.

Two sum in linear time after sorting -> 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650614/4723446

public class ThreeSum {

```
private static int countThreeSum(int[] numbers) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int front = 0, rear = numbers.length - 1;

        while (front < rear) {
            if (numbers[front] + numbers[rear] + numbers[i] == 0) {
                System.out.printf(String.format("Front : {%d}  Rear : {%d}  I : {%d}  \n", numbers[front],
                        numbers[rear], numbers[i]));
                front++;
                rear--;
                count++;
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(numbers[front]) > Math.abs(numbers[rear])) {
                    front++;
                } else {
                    rear--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 12, 16, 19, 15, 11, 8, -1, -3, -7, -8, -11, -17, -15 };
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(countThreeSum(numbers));
}
```

}

Comment: i and front have the same value here

Answer (score 1):

It's worked with any NSum (3Sum, 4Sum, 5Sum, ...) and quite fast.

```
public class ThreeSum {
private static final int RANDOM_RANGE = 20;
private Integer array[];
private Integer arrayIndex[];
private int result[];
private int bagLength;
private int resultIndex = 0;

private void generateData(int size) {
    array = new Integer[size];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt(RANDOM_RANGE) - (RANDOM_RANGE/2);
    }
}

private void markArrayIndex(int size) {
    arrayIndex = new Integer[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arrayIndex[i] = i;
    }
}

private void prepareBeforeCalculate(int size, int sumExpected, int bagLength) {
    this.bagLength = bagLength;
    result = new int[bagLength];
    generateData(size);
    markArrayIndex(size);
}

void calculate(int size, int sumExpected, int bagLength) {
    prepareBeforeCalculate(size, sumExpected, bagLength);

    Arrays.sort(arrayIndex, (l, r) -> array[l].compareTo(array[r]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    long startAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (sumExpected > 0) findLeft(sumExpected, 0, 0, array.length);
    else findRight(sumExpected, 0, 0 - 1, array.length - 1);

    System.out.println("Calculating in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startAt) / 1000));
}

private void findLeft(int total, int indexBag, int left, int right) {
    while (left < array.length && array[arrayIndex[left]] < 0 && indexBag < bagLength) {
        navigating(total, arrayIndex[left], indexBag, left, right);
        left++;
    }
}

private void findRight(int total, int indexBag, int left, int right) {
    while (right >= 0 && array[arrayIndex[right]] >= 0 && indexBag < bagLength) {
        navigating(total, arrayIndex[right], indexBag, left, right);
        right--;
    }
}

private void navigating(int total, int index, int indexBag, int left, int right) {
    result[indexBag] = index;
    total += array[index];
    if (total == 0 && indexBag == bagLength - 1) {
        System.out.println(String.format("R[%d] %s", resultIndex++, toResultString()));
        return;
    }

    if (total > 0) findLeft(total, indexBag + 1, left + 1, right);
    else findRight(total, indexBag + 1, left, right - 1);
}

private String toResultString() {
    int [] copyResult = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length);
    Arrays.sort(copyResult);

    int iMax = copyResult.length - 1;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(array[copyResult[i]]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ThreeSumTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    ThreeSum test = new ThreeSum();
    test.calculate(100, 0, 3);
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

}