# How can I solve the 3-sum challenge using arrayLists?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I'm currently trying to solve the "three sum" challenge (I'm using java by the way). Here is the challenge description:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Example:

Given array nums = `[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]`,

A solution set is:

```
[
  [-1, 0, 1],
  [-1, -1, 2]
]
```

Here is my attempted solution but it is not working currently:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {

        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <  nums.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                        subList.add(nums[i]);
                        subList.add(nums[j]);
                        subList.add(nums[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        result.add(subList);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[[-1,0,1,-1,2,-1,0,1,-1]]
```

When it is supposed to be:

```
[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

I know my attempted solution is O(n^(3)) and not optimal, but I'm curious on how I can do this challenge using three for loops. Can someone give me an idea on how I can go about creating the right output ? I've been trying different things to no avail. Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to implement 3 sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905695/java-how-to-implement-3-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a solution, pleas instantly add it to the results list:

```java
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {

        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <  nums.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
                        subList.add(nums[i]);
                        subList.add(nums[j]);
                        subList.add(nums[k]);
                        result.add(subList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This will give you:
`[[-1,0,1],[-1,2,-1],[0,1,-1]]`

In this case, the `[-1,0,1]` option is added twice, because `-1` is in the list twice, depending whether or not you want this, you can sort the sublist, and check for equality:

```java
public class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {

        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <  nums.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
                        subList.add(nums[i]);
                        subList.add(nums[j]);
                        subList.add(nums[k]);

                        Collections.sort(subList);
                        boolean duplicate = false;

                        for (List<Integer> list : result) {
                            if (list.equals(subList)) {
                                duplicate = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!duplicate) {                            
                            result.add(subList);
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Your solution made the correct output, but it won't pass on LeetCode because of a bizarre test case: [82597,-9243,62390,83030,-97960,-26521,-61011,83390,-38677,12333,75987,46091,83794,19355,-71037,-6242,-28801,324,1202,-90885,-2989,-95597,-34333,35528,5680,89093,-90606,50360,-29393,-27012,53313,65213,99818,-82405,-41661,-3333,-51952,72135,-1523,26377,74685,96992,92263,15929,5467,-99555,-43348,-41689,-60383,-3990,32165,65265,-72973,-58372,12741,-48568,-46596,7...] . I did this solution because it was intuitive for me at least. I appreciate the help though !

Comment: Ah, probably that test is there to rule out slow (O(n^3)) implementations... I have experience with that as well. If you are going to try to make it faster, I can give you the hint that sorting might help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put  `result.add(subList)` inside of your if statement after your subList.add() statements. Currently in your code, you are adding every solution to the sublist without ever adding it to the result, so at the end you simply are adding a list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues here:

1. `result.add(subList);` You're adding your `sublist` at the very end of the computations.
2. You never clear previous results from your `sublist`.

You need to declare:

```
List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside the 2nd loop and before the 3rd one AND add your sublist after you've added all 3 numbers but only if there was a coincidence (i.e. all 3 numbers added are equal to zero)

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <  nums.length - 1; j++) {
        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                subList.add(nums[i]);
                subList.add(nums[j]);
                subList.add(nums[k]);
            }
        }
        if (!subList.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(subList);
        }
    }
}
```

This provides this result:

```
[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, -1], [0, 1, -1]]
```

And now we need to have them as **unique** combinations, so, we could use:

```
Collections.sort(sublist)
```

And change our `result` variable to be a `Set` rather than a `List`, so, our code will end up as:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public static Set<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {

        Set<List<Integer>> result = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <  nums.length - 1; j++) {
                List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                        subList.add(nums[i]);
                        subList.add(nums[j]);
                        subList.add(nums[k]);
                    }
                }
                Collections.sort(subList);
                if (!subList.isEmpty()) {
                    result.add(subList);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(threeSum(new int[] {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4}));
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

**Note:** I made the method `static` in order to test the program without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  The first and most obvious is that you've merely appended the elements to the array, without making a 3-element sub-array from them.  You can fix that easily:

```
                    subList.add(nums[i]);
                    subList.add(nums[j]);
                    subList.add(nums[k]);
```

Should be
                        subList.add([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]);

---

The second problem is that your program doesn't recognize that the -1 values are not considered separate solutions to the remaining pair of [1, 0].  The easiest way to get around this is to sort the list before you begin, and check that your third element can be only one of any grouping.

Finally, to consolidate the gains of that sorting, your loop nesting should ensure that you never pick the same elements in a different order.  You're handling your indexing correctly, but eliminate the third loop.  Merely check to see whether the sum you need is available.  In pseudo-code ...

```
        if (-(nums[i] + nums[j]) is in nums[j+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin way

```
    fun main() {
       println(ThreeSum(readLine()))
    }

    fun ThreeSum(nums: Array<Int>): Boolean {

 if(nums.size < 4) return false  //minimum 4 elements should be in array
 
  var counter = 0
  for (i in 0..(nums.size - 3)) {
            for (j in  (i + 1)..(nums.size - 3)) {
                for (k in  (j + 1)..(nums.size-1)) {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == nums[0]) {
                        counter+=1 
                        if (counter == 3) {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
  return false
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> three=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length-2;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length-1;j++){
                for(int k=j+1;k<nums.length;k++){
                    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
                            if(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]==0){
                                list.add(nums[i]);
                                list.add(nums[j]);
                                list.add(nums[k]);
                                Collections.sort(list);
                                boolean duplicate = false;
                                
                                for (List<Integer> l : three) {
                                    if (three.equals(list)) {
                                        duplicate = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                        if (!duplicate) {
                            if(!three.contains(list)){
                                three.add(list);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }  
        }  
    }
    return three;
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).